# Jquery event for select tag closing

Tags: jquery, events, select

I can hook into the change event of the select fine (Which will cause the select to close), which is not a problem. But I also need to detect when the select tag is closed by way of clicking on the screen elsewhere.

So far everything I've tried hasn't worked; body click, body focus, select blur, select focusout are among the few combinations.

With most of them it will only register on the second click on the body, so:
Click1) Select closes, event doesn't fire.
Click2) Event fires.

I know I could create my own version of a select tag (And have done so before), but it seems a bit overkill for this situation when the normal select is fine, I just need this one event.

Cheer, Psy

Comment: Which versions of IE are you supporting? Older IE versions used a *very* different control for the `<select>` element, they grabbed it right from winforms so it behaves in a very odd way with respect to...well, everything really.

Comment: @Nick, IE7 ideally, if not IE8, most people I know who'll be using it will be on Chrome/FF/Safari anyway.

Comment: I've wasted much life on this as well. You can try something gross like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480695/detecting-interaction-with-select-box. It basically forces the change event to work in your situation .... but it's super gross.

Comment: @Psytronic "when the select tag is closed". Please described the "closed" state, as `html`, `css`, or `js` variable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Sounds like a blur thang...**

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    //change things here 
}).on('blur', function() {
    //when select is no longer in focus here
});
```

[**Made a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/Rm7p8/)