# Detecting interaction with select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select, dom-events

How (using Javascript or jQuery) can I detect when a value has been selected from a select box, even if it's the same option as was previously selected (i.e. no change event is fired).

Mainly I need this for mouse interaction, but a solution that works for keyboard too would be handy.

Comment: Chances are that you are trying to go about whatever it is the wrong way. May I ask why you want this behavior? Personally, I oppose changing browser behavior.

Comment: @Tyler Crompton I have some rows in a table populated by Backbone and some of the columns contain a select box to display and allow changing of the value. I want to save a timestamp for the time the user last interracted with a record and it's important to record even interactions that result in no change. Basically, for my purposes a user evaluating and considering changing the value is as important as them actually changing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found workable is to cause `change` event by setting the value of `select` to some other on `mousedown`. In the markup I created one extra option (i.e. the first child) and made it hidden (hides perfectly in Chrome/FF/Safari, IE as usual). So it looks fine.

```
<select>
    <option style="display: none"></option>
    <option>First</option>
    <option>Second</option>
    <option>Third</option>
</select>​
```

Then using jQuery we bind `change` and `mousedown` events in a way that when `mousedown` triggers, `select` resets its value to the value of the hidden option.

```
$("select").on({
    change: function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    },
    mousedown: function() {
        $(this).val($(":first", this).val());
    }
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LzNrS/

**UPDATE:** In order to preserve the selected value when user has clicked on `select` but decided not the choose anything, we can modify the code a bit adding `blur` event and updating `mousedown`.

```
var special = ""; // special hidden option value
var value = ""; // temporary variable

$("select").on({
    change: function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    },
    mousedown: function() {
        if (this.value == special) {
            $(this).val(value);
            return;
        }
        value = this.value;
        $(this).val(special);
    },
    blur: function() {
        if (this.value == special)
            $(this).val(value);
    }
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LzNrS/1/

Comment: Also consider keyboard navigation as the OP mentioned. Good work.

Comment: Nice solution. Eventually, as there doesn't seem to be a totally straightforward solution, I decided to circumvent the problem by displaying the current value in an adjacent label and having the select update this value then reset to default option "please confirm status" after each change event.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if it would work just from the top of my head if you could attach an event handler to the select box option element and on click store its value.

works with mouse, doesn't work with keyboard http://jsfiddle.net/w4DEJ/4/

Answer (score 0):

I think focus() function will help you..try this:
http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question