# AngularJS way to detect selecting the same <option> in <select> dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

`ng-change` doesn't fire if you select the same option. I'm using a dropdown box to select a sort order, and want selecting the same value to re-sort by the same criteria.

On Chrome I can't get anything to work. I've tried firing an `ng-click` event on the select itself, the options, and on a containing element, but the click doesn't seem to propagate up.

I've tried using `ng-focus` and `ng-blur`, but focus happens before they've actually selected any option, and blur doesn't happen until the user actually clicks away from the dropdown, after having selected an option. That would work, but is a bit weird because nothing happens at first.

I've also tried `ng-mousedown` and `ng-mouseup` - mouseup doesn't seem to fire, and mousedown, like focus, fires before they select an option.

There is a very ugly workaround here: [Detecting interaction with select box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10480695), but it won't even work for me because mousedown isn't firing.

There has to be some way to do this! My last-resort hack is to basically build a dropdown from scratch without using `<select>`.

Comment: or add a "refresh" button near the select which triggers a re-sort.

Comment: this is one of the multitude of reasons so many select replacements scripts have been created. Has nothing to do with anything angular, has to do with browsers. They won't register event on already selectd single option

Comment: I feared as much... I will just put a refresh button until/unless someone comes up with something really fancy.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("MyCtrl", function() {
  this.data = ['price', 'user', 'date', 'color'];

  this.sort = function(param) {
    console.log("Sort by : " + param);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
    <select>
      <option ng-click="ctrl.sort(opt)" ng-repeat="opt in ctrl.data">{{opt}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```